# Is there a ことわざ similar to "water under the bridge" and "let bygones be bygones"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, proverbs

Earlier today in a comment I tried to explain to a community member that they should put whatever happened in the past behind them. I used "water behind the bridge" and "let bygones be bygones". For context, the two English idioms are:

[water under the bridge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/water%20under%20the%20bridge)

> —used to say that something happened in the past and is no longer important or worth arguing about
> *We had our differences in the past, but that's all water under the bridge now.*

[let bygones be bygones](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%20bygones%20be%20bygones)

> to forgive someone for something done or for a disagreement and to forget about it
> *I know we've had our fights over the years, but I think it's time we let bygones be bygones.*

I've found [some explanations of the two phrases in Japanese](https://native-phrase-blog.com/its-water-under-the-bridge-%EF%BC%9A%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AF%E3%82%82%E3%81%86%E9%81%8E%E3%81%8E%E3%81%9F%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A0%E3%82%88/) but have yet to find a corresponding ことわざ.

Comment: You might also wanna check out [既往は咎めず](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%97%A2%E5%BE%80%E3%81%AF%E5%92%8E%E3%82%81%E3%81%9A-472298).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oddly enough we say 水に流す。E.g.昔のことは水に流して仲良くやろう。

Comment: Ahh I have heard this one before!